# Right Ascension of the Ascending Node (RAAN) Drift and Correction

Tags: orbital-maneuver, orbital-elements, station-keeping

This one can be a very short and easy question, but I wanna know the proper answer of them..

Few days ago I got a questions like:

1. "What kind of perturbation(s) can cause drift on RAAN value of a highly inclined satellite?"

as a follow up that question one also came up as:

2. "What kind of maneuver can we do in order to correct that drift? In-Plane (E/W) or Out-of-Plane (N/S)? Or mix of them?"

I believe I had some proper answers for those questions, but I doubt it at the same time.. So, what you guys thinking of them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have changed to "drift" from "drag". My bad, sorry..

Comment: thanks! 1. sounds like [nodal precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_precession) and 2. I guess a costly, continuous plane change maneuver, there's probably some place around the eccentric orbit where it would be most effective. (for some reason there's nothing about plane changing maneuvers in Wikipedia's [Orbital maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_maneuver))

Comment: Thank you! This explanation more than enough to me. At least it clears my doubts.. [Here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/III.4.1.5_Maneuvering_in_Space.pdf) you can find an explicit document to get more detailed examples about the out of plane maneuvers and all the other ones.

Comment: Although I am agree with you @uhoh mostly, but I am thinking that we may need a mix maneuver strategy.. I do not think we can solve it doing only plane change, am I wrong? Since the raan drift formula (nodal precession) contains both i and e, I thought like that. Correct me if I am wrong for sure..

Comment: *Nodal precession* is a continuous plane change and nothing else. If you execute a plane change maneuver of the opposite sign, you 'll zero out RAAN drift.

Comment: Okay, now I got it! Thank you for your all explanations @uhoh! So, the final result will be the doing a plane change maneuver.

Comment: I'm no expert on this topic at all, so I haven't posted an actual answer. I'm hoping that someone else will. If you are convinced then you are welcome to post an answer to your own question, which is always okay in Stack Exchange! If you include a link or citation or a plane change maneuver description and mention at what point in an elliptical orbit is the best place to do it, then I think you've got a very nice answer.

Comment: Okay, that was my main idea but I would like to wait a little, some one might still post an answer. If not, I will try to summarize the answer!

Comment: If you try to answer both questions at once, keep in mind that for any inclined satellite, in-plane and out-of-plane are rotated by the Euler angles, so you get both $\sin i$ and $\cos i$ and $\sin \Omega$ and $\cos \Omega$ terms which mix E-W with N-S.  For an exactly polar-orbiting satellite, N-S is in-plane, and a purely E-W maneuver adjusts only $\Omega$, not $i$!